# Pointer to a constant

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   const int a1 = 40;
   const int* b1 = &a1;
   int * c1 = (int *)(b1);
   *c1 = 'A';
cout<<*c1<<endl;
cout<<a1<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

o/p:

```
65
40
```

Can anyone explain the output?

Comment: It is undefined behaviour. You are casting away the constness of something that really is `const`.

Comment: akash: As Raymond Chen says, "Don't write code like this". There's no good reason to write such crap or to care what it does or how.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour and it depends on compiler to give you an error or any answer. Standard defines it undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is casting away the constness of something that is `const` (variable `a1`). This results in *undefined behaviour* (UB). In practice it means that anything could happen. What you observe is one manifestation of "anything".

Usually answers to questions involving UB include wild examples of crazy things that could happen. I will break with tradition by refraining from that.

Comment: The "tradition" is stupid. Even conforming programs can do anything at all because no implementation, or instance of an implementation, can be guaranteed to be conforming. All the standard says is what will happen *if* a conforming program is executed by a conforming implementation ... and "undefined behavior" is simply behavior that isn't defined by the standard. But defined by the standard or not, implementations are deterministic components of the real world and have predictable behaviors given the right level of knowledge.

Comment: Would it still have been undefined behavior if he had used `const_cast`?

Comment: @JimBalter: Actually, no, systems stopped being deterministic quite a few years ago. Multi-threaded programs with improper locking can run into race conditions which are thermally dependent (!). Temperature affects the outcome, and as modern CPU's run near the  limits of Quantum Mechanics, this behavior is not predictable. Of course, well-defined programs do not have such race conditions.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Yes, the spelling does not matter, the cast itself is UB.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of it if it won't work in this scenario?

Comment: @0x499602D2 what is the purpose of what? `const_cast`? It can be used legitimately when the argument is not itself `const`. But there are very few situations where its use is justified.

Comment: @MSalters Right, it is one of those situations where "the right level of knowledge" needs more bits than could be held in all the particles of the universe :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Physicist by training here. When I wrote "Quantum Mechanics", I meant it. It's not that you run out of bits. Heck, Schrodinger's cat needs only a single bit. You just cannot have the knowledge to predict the result before observing it.

Comment: @MSalters ex-physicist here too. Was only joking.

Comment: @MSalters: Where can temperature affect the observable behaviour of the system? (Other than when it's taken beyond its operating limits, of course...)  In other words, what component takes more/fewer cycles?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Any modern CPU has temperature throttling, and hitting that is not considered "beyond operating limits".

Comment: @MSalters: Ah ok.  You threw me off by talking about QM!

Comment: @MSalters *actually* you're indulging in a stupid and irrelevant quibble ... my point was clear enough.

Comment: *it is one of those situations where "the right level of knowledge" needs more bits than could be held in all the particles of the universe :-)* -- **What** is one of those situations? Certainly not the UB being discussed in this question. And as I said but MSalters foolishly ignored, even conforming programs can do anything because, y'know, the language standard can't outlaw QM so it can't guarantee that there's any such thing as a conforming implementation. All implementations run on real hardware and are subject to physical uncertainties. So this is a dumb digression from my valid point.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of "undefined behaviour", which explains why you are getting two different outputs "from one variable". Undefined behaviour, means "not necessarily what you expect, but could be what you expect".

Since you have "promised" the compiler that you are not going to change `a1`, then the compiler simply puts the constant `40` into the `cout << a1 << endl` line, rather than actually reading the value in `a1`. This is an optimization that is perfectly valid for a constant. The fact that you then jump through hoops to manage to "loose" the constness of that variable and write to it doesn't really change the fact that you promised not to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment `*c1 = 'A';` writes to unwritable memory. Hopefully you know that's bad. I'll assume there's a less stupid reason for writing the code and asking people to explain it.

Maybe you want an example of how implementation choices can lead to the result you saw. Here's one: the compiler optimizes away all the reads of the variable: to print `*c1` it says "I don't need to look at `*c1`, I know what's in it, I just put a 65 there. I'll print that." And then to print `a1` it says "I don't need to look at `a1`, I initialized it to 40 and it's not allowed to change, so I'll just print that." Then it looks at the `*c1` assignment and says "I don't really need to assign that value, since I'm not going to use it."

Or maybe that last part doesn't happen. The variable is local, so it's likely to be on the stack, in a writable page, without meaningful run-time enforcement of its constness.